# Then series $\sum(a_n)$ converges or diverges

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

The series is defined as $a_n=(n+1)^{\frac{1}{2}} - (n)^{\frac{1}{2}}$.

So if I can show that the partial sum $s_{n}$ is convergent then I am done.

Now I get my

$s_n = (n+1)^{\frac{1}{2}}-1$ . If i simplify it I will get,

$s_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt(\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2})+\frac{1}{n}}$

The limit of which is infinity. Hence the series also diverges. Is this ok?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done easier. We can notice, that:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}=
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{n+1} = 
\infty$$

Answer (score 2):

To be more rigorous, if
$a_n
=(n+1)^{\frac{1}{2}} - (n)^{\frac{1}{2}}
$
then

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{n=1}^m a_n
&=\sum_{n=1}^m ((n+1)^{\frac{1}{2}} - (n)^{\frac{1}{2}})\\
&=(m+1)^{\frac{1}{2}} - 1\\
&\to \infty
\quad\text{ as } m \to \infty\\
\end{array}
$

Note that this holds if
$a_n
=f(n+1)-f(n)
$
where
$f(n+1) > f(n)
$
and
$f(n) \to \infty$.

This is the case
$f(n) = \sqrt{n}$.